# Calling a virtual function from a destructor of a derived class in c++

Tags: c++

Here is a snippet of my c++ code

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void method() {
        cout << "A::method" << endl;
    }

    virtual ~A() {
        cout << "A::destructor" << endl;
    }

};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void method() {
        cout << "B::method" << endl;
    }

    virtual ~B() {
        cout << "B::destructor" << endl;
        method();
    }
};

int _tmain()
{    
    A* a = new B();

    a->method();

    delete a;

    return 0;
}
```

I've learned that it's not preferable to call any virtual functions from constructors or destructors.
In the destructor of the derived class B, I call the virtual function named, "method()".

Here is the output message.

```
B::method
B::destructor
B::method
A::destructor
```

It seems to me there is no problem at all. The virtual function knows its object type and printed
"B::method()". Is this a kind of undefined behavior that should be avoided?

Comment: It's not UB, it's not a programming error. It's just error-prone and requires extra care. If you can refactor your program to avoid it, you'll have fewer bugs in the future and your future-self and other fellow team members will love you for it.

Comment: Now, try and define `class C : public B` overriding `method` and see what happens when you create and destroy an object of type `C`.

Comment: @YSC
I just defined class C.

class C : public B {
public:
    virtual void method() {
        cout << "C::method" << endl;
    }

    virtual ~C() {
        cout << "C::destructor" << endl;
        method();
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    
    A* a = new C();

    a->method();

    delete a;

    return 0;
}

and the output message is here:
C::method
C::destructor
C::method
B::destructor
B::method
A::destructor

Comment: Yes. If this is the expected behaviour of your program, fine-ish. If not you've got a bug and a quite hard one to track down. [demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05ac947e928ad2b3)

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I'm convinced that using virtual functions from constructors or destructos should be avoided for my future-self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually all the virtual functions in `B` are accessible in the destructor body, so your code is fine and well-defined as it is.

But your code is extremely brittle: it would be a different matter if there was a child class of `B` which had `method` overridden. In that case writing `B::method();` in the destructor body of `B` would be sufficient.

Short answer: calling virtual methods in constructors and destructors is best avoided.